# Vue-select component select value programatically

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, vue-select

Im using vuejs and vue-select component , and wonder how can I programatically tell him to select an array in the options ?

Comment: could you provide some tried code?

Comment: please share your code so that others can understand whats problem or lacking on it .

Comment: you need to set `v-model` as object ```{value: "myval", label: "Option Label"}```